# Can't rename lstlistoflistings on ShareLatex

Tags: listings, lists, sharelatex

I cant rename the `\lstlistoflistings` page title `Contents` in any way. I've tried all the solutions I found so far, and nothing worked.

In case it might help:
In my project, I've created a new listing environment with the code below. It works perfectly.

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][language=Python,caption=Name,label=code:Name]
  {
  \if\@language0
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Bloco de Código}%
  \else
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code Block}
  \fi
  \lstset{
    #1,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    aboveskip={1.0\baselineskip},
    belowskip={1.0\baselineskip},
    columns=fixed,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    tabsize=4,
    prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    frame=lines,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{01,0,0},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=10pt,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
    }
    }
  {}
```

The entire project is available on ShareLatex: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/590cc194997d9db520860b9b

And on GitHub : https://github.com/auyer/IFBtcc/tree/codeBlock.Feature

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where did you find that code?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. That code is what I used to customize the listings. I know it does not affect \lstlistoflistings direcly, but since it's the only difference I found from other similar stackexchange  questions, I decided to add it here.

Comment: I tried to have a look at the project, but I find the code very messy. Sorry.

Comment: I am confused: The question is tagged sharelatex, but the project is on github?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes. ShareLatex is the Editor I use.  I can create a public project on ShareLatex as well. But all the files are on github.

Comment: Please try to reduce your problem to a minimal compilable version that shows the issue. I won't go over to github and glue a document together that might finally work, but is totally different your setup

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've created a Public Project on ShareLatex : https://www.sharelatex.com/project/590cc194997d9db520860b9b

Comment: @RafaelAuyer: The github 'project' is a mess and screws up many things -- it seems to be a glue of many different code sources, which is very frequent for 'designers' that have absolutely no idea how to setup files correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`\lstnewenvironment`** is used to set the listing environment not the rendering of the table of listings content.
As I saw in your sharelatex public code, you are using the packages `listings` and `tocbibind`. The `listings` package provides a list of listings table of content as explained by their documentation. So to fix what you requested you should remove this modifications from the environment and let it be like this:

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1]

[language=Python,caption=Name,label=code:Name]
  {
  \lstset{
    #1,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    aboveskip={1.0\baselineskip},
    belowskip={1.0\baselineskip},
    columns=fixed,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    tabsize=4,
    prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    frame=lines,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{01,0,0},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=10pt,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
    }
  }
 {}
```

Defines `\gdef\@lstlistingname{title name here}` this var for every language that you will use with the table of content title. And, finally, you should use `\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings` to define the page format. Looking at you latex project it should be something like this:

```
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \chapter*{\@lstlistingname}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \@starttoc{lol}}
```

The aforementioned modifications were tested in your public project, so it works. Take a look! ;)

Cheers!